# Magento 2: How to apply css in the second div of toolbar?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, frontend, toolbar

I'm try to appply css in second div of toolbar class, but my css is applied in both div, so can you give me suggestion how to apply css for particular second div in toolbar class ?

**Here is a screenshot, pleas check for better understanding.**

[image]

Comment: You can get second class with .products-grid + .toolbar-products

Update first match class with direct .toolbar-products {}

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can try to use [CSS element1~element2 Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp) for second element

```
// first toolbar
.toolbar.toolbar-products:first {
    // ...
}
// second toolbar
.toolbar.toolbar-products ~ .toolbar.toolbar-products {
     // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `+ .toolbar-products` for applied css.

```
.toolbar-products { color:yellow}
.products-grid + .toolbar-products { color:red}
```